# Creating a tag longer than 25 characters

Tags: feature-request, tags

Today I wanted to add a "conversion-centered-design" tag, but it is 26 characters long. At the same time, "ccd" may be harder to understand. Any way out of this?

Comment: You're not alone here. It's particularly a problem over at gaming.stackexchange - http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/increase-tag-length-limit-to-30-characters However it looks like it's not going to change. Tag length  is too rooted onto the code and isn't going to change anytime soon, apparently.